# Is Aristotle referring to both Posterior Analytics and Prior Analytics when referring to simply "Analytics"?

Tags: terminology, aristotle

In Book I, Part 2 of Aristotle's *Rhetoric*, Aristotle writes:

> With regard to the persuasion achieved by proof or apparent proof:
>   just as in dialectic there is induction on the one hand and syllogism
>   or apparent syllogism on the other, so it is in rhetoric. The example
>   is an induction, the enthymeme is a syllogism, and the apparent enthymeme
>   is an apparent syllogism. I call the enthymeme a rhetorical syllogism,
>   and the example a rhetorical induction. Every one who effects persuasion
>   through proof does in fact use either enthymemes or examples: there
>   is no other way. And since every one who proves anything at all is
>   bound to use either syllogisms or inductions (and this is clear to
>   us from **the Analytics**), it must follow that enthymemes are syllogisms
>   and examples are inductions.

When Aristotle says, "the *Analytics*," is Aristotle here referring to *Posterior Analytics*, *Prior Analytics*, or both *Posterior Analytics* and *Prior Analytics*? I do not think there is a precise timeline of these works and *Rhetoric*, so I would appreciate if an educated scholar gave me a definitive reply.

Update 1:

The phrase is used again in Book I, Part 2 here:

> There are few facts of the 'necessary' type that can form the basis
>   of rhetorical syllogisms. Most of the things about which we make decisions,
>   and into which therefore we inquire, present us with alternative possibilities.
>   For it is about our actions that we deliberate and inquire, and all
>   our actions have a contingent character; hardly any of them are determined
>   by necessity. Again, conclusions that state what is merely usual or
>   possible must be drawn from premisses that do the same, just as 'necessary'
>   conclusions must be drawn from 'necessary' premisses; this too is
>   clear to us from **the Analytics**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at *Rhetoric* (translated by W. Rhys Roberts with footnotes) thanks to my local library. Aristotle is ambiguous for stylistic ease---he varies between referencing *Posterior Analytics* and *Prior Analytics* when he says "the *Analytics*". Sometimes he means one of the two, other times he means both. In other words, he is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that Aristotle is ambiguous. It's that both texts are reconstructions. Thus, we don't know exactly what sequence of items were in the text he calls the *Analytics*